# Set Yoast title in template for custom post type archive

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

I'm using [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/) plugin. I've got a custom post type that was initially setup as "news"... this was then changed to "blog". Even though the archive settings are set to be called "Blog", when posting the link in linkedin, the snippet still shows up as News.

Is there a way to explicitly set the Yoast title in the template?

[image]

Comment: how did you create your custom post type ?

Answer (score 1):

open up your database and search for the table `wp_posts` now look for the sql box that will have `SELECT * FROM wp_posts` written in it, in the bottom right corner of that box you will see "Edit Inline" left-click on that and now edit the sql to look like this `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "%blog%"`

If anything comes up then you need to change it to the new title

**Please Note**: Always backup your database before making any changes

Answer (score 0):

Try updating permalinks structure and clear all catch after it.
Change your post type completely to Blog from News As its showing you **Settings for News archive** this means you have not compltely changed the news to blog add

```
'name' => _x( 'Blog', 'blog' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Blog', 'blog' ),
```

To your post type labels array, your problem will get solved if not, go to http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_titles#top#post-types
and save it once again after changing the above code.

Comment: Can you please show the code you have used to change th post type blog from news

Comment: I have changed my answer please check it if it works